# PV01 of Physically settled Swaptions contrat

Tags: swaption

Can you please help me figure out how to find PV01 Physically settled Swaptions contract 20Y30Y with fwd rate 0.01974  with fixed freq=2, using ACT/360 with 02/08/2019 -> 02/08/2039 and 02/08/2069 showing calculating step by step would be helpful thank you

Comment: Up please, I'm still looking for an answer ...